# WCF Rest - no elemnt found error

Tags: wcf, jquery, cross-domain, wcf-rest

I designed a WCF REST service and try to consume it via JQuery in html page. When I added the html page in the solution where WCF service was created, I was getting the result as per the need. But when I created the HTML Page in a different solution I started getting errors such as no element found and the returned result is null.

**I put a debugger in the service and I noticed that even if the the Consumer html page is kept in a different solution it still hits the global.asax file when service is called, But its not hitting any of the Method.
I even put "crossDomain:true," and "jQuery.support.cors = true;" in script for enabling Cross Domain problem as well as I have made changes in Global.asax file too but of no use.
Please provide me the solution for the same asap.**

I am placing the actual code with configuration files and DataContracts along with the HTML code here :

ICouponService.cs :

```
    [ServiceContract]
public interface ICouponService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GenerateCoupon",
        Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    CouponData GenerateCoupon(CouponData objCustomerData);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/UpdateGeneratedCoupon",
        Method = "POST",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ResponseMessage UpdateGeneratedCoupon(CouponData objCustomerData);
}
```

CouponService.cs :

```
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class CouponService : ICouponService
{

    public CouponData GenerateCoupon(CouponData objCustomerData)
    {
return objCouponData;
    }


    public ResponseMessage UpdateGeneratedCoupon(CouponData objCustomerData)
    {
return objResponseMessage;

    }
    }
```

CouponData.cs :

```
    [DataContract]
    public class CouponData
    {
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Points { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string ActiveFlag { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string CouponCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string RequestID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string LoyaltyID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Result { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string ReturnFlag { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

ResponseMessage.cs :

```
    [DataContract]
public class ResponseMessage
{
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public string Response { get; set; }
}
```

Global.asax :
First I thought there might be some Header problem so I added the same in Global file as shown below :

```
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sessionId = Session.SessionID;
    }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall();
    }

    private void EnableCrossDomainAjaxCall()
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ORIGIN"]))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ORIGIN"]); 
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod))
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS" || HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST" || HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
                    //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Web.config :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="SAM_STORE_LoyaltyProgram_WCFLibrary.CouponService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
      contract="SAM_STORE_LoyaltyProgram_WCFLibrary.ICouponService" />
   </service>
   <service name="SAM_STORE_LoyaltyProgram_WCFServices.qqq">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="SAM_STORE_LoyaltyProgram_WCFServices.qqqAspNetAjaxBehavior"
      binding="webHttpBinding" contract="SAM_STORE_LoyaltyProgram_WCFServices.qqq" />
   </service>
   </services>
   <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="SAM_STORE_LoyaltyProgram_WCFServices.qqqAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="5000" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferSize="5000" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000"
      transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="5000" maxStringContentLength="5000"
        maxArrayLength="5000" maxBytesPerRead="5000" maxNameTableCharCount="5000" />
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Index.html (script used to call service):

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Type;
    var Url;
    var Data;
    var ContentType;
    var DataType;
    var ProcessData;
    var method;
    var eMail;
    var points;
    var requestId;
    var couponCode;
    var returnFlag;
    var userName;
    var password;

    //Generic function to call Service
    function CallService() {
        $.ajax({
            type: Type,
            url: Url,
            data: Data,
            contentType: ContentType,
            dataType: DataType,
            //crossDomain:true,  --This is not working
            processdata: ProcessData,
            success: function (msg) {
                ServiceSucceeded(msg);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Service Failed");
                ServiceFailed(msg);
            }
        });
    }

    function SetGenerateCouponValues() {
        eMail = $("#txtEmail").val();
        points = $("#txtPoints").val();
        requestId = $("#txtRequestId").val();
        userName = 'username';
        password = 'JEBtJHVu';
    }

    function DestroyGenerateCouponValues() {
        eMail = null;
        points = null;
        requestId = null;
        userName = null;
        password = null;
    }

    function SetUpdateCouponValues() {
        couponCode = $("#txtCode").val();
        returnFlag = $("#txtFlag").val();
        userName = 'username';
        password = 'JEBtJHVu';
    }

    function DestroyUpdateCouponValues() {
        couponCode = null;
        returnFlag = null;
        userName = null;
        password = null;

    }

    function ServiceFailed(result) {
        alert('Service call failed: ' + result.status + '' + result.statusText);
        Type = null; Url = null; Data = null; ContentType = null; DataType = null; ProcessData = null;
    }

    function GenerateCoupon() {
        SetGenerateCouponValues();
        Type = "POST";
        Url = "ServiceURL";
        Data = '{ "Email": "' + eMail + '",   "Points": "' + points + '",  "UserName": "' + userName + '",  "Password": "' + password + '",  "RequestID": "' + requestId + '"}';
        ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        DataType = "json";
        ProcessData = true;
        method = "GenerateCoupon";
        CallService();
        DestroyGenerateCouponValues();
    }

    function UpdateGeneratedCoupon() {
        SetUpdateCouponValues();
        Type = "POST";
        Url = "ServiceURL";
        Data = '{ "CouponCode": "' + couponCode + '",   "ReturnFlag": "' + returnFlag + '",  "UserName": "' + userName + '",  "Password": "' + password + '"}';
        ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        DataType = "json";
        ProcessData = true;
        method = "UpdateGeneratedCoupon";
        CallService();
        DestroyUpdateCouponValues();
    }

    function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
        if (DataType == "json") {
            if (method == "GenerateCoupon") {
                var string = "Coupon Code : " + result.CouponCode + "<br/>" + "Points : " + result.Points + "<br/>" + "Result : " + result.Result;
                $("#resultCreate").html(string);
                $("#lblCouponCode").text(result.CouponCode);
                $("#lblPoints").text(result.Points);
                $("#lblResult").text(result.Result);
            }
            else if (method == "UpdateGeneratedCoupon") {
                var string = "Response : " + result.Response;
                $("#resultDelete").html(string);
                $("#lblResponse").text(result.Response);
            }
        }
    }

    /*function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
    alert("FAIL" + xhr.responseText);
    if (xhr.responseText) {
    var err = xhr.responseText;
    if (err)
    error(err);
    else
    error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
    }
    return;
    }*/

    $(document).ready(
     function () {
         //jQuery.support.cors = true;  --This is not working

         $("#btnsubmit").click(function () {
             GenerateCoupon();
         });

         $("#btnUpdateGeneratedCoupon").click(function () {
             UpdateGeneratedCoupon();
         });
     });
</script>
```

**Please provide me the solution for the same asap.**

Comment: This code is working fine with IE10 and other browsers when deployed on IIS but it's still causing problem with IE9 and below versions of IE. On IE it shows and Error - "Access is Denied."

Answer (score 0):

Is it calling ServiceSucceeded method?? 
If ServiceSucceeded  called try to put **$.support.cors = true;**  in CallService() starting and then check it

Comment: Yes, it is calling ServiceSucceeded method, and I also tried the code $.support.cors = true; but it still shows the same error, no element found.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and [ETW tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751538.aspx) to see what is happening at the server side while invoking the service operation.

Comment: I tried this too but I didn't get any helpful information from the log ie. the log file does not contains any error.

Comment: Did you see the request coming in to the service?

Comment: As I have posted above, This code is working fine with IE10 and other browsers when deployed on IIS but it's still causing problem with IE9 and below versions of IE. On IE it shows and Error - "Access is Denied.", and in IE9 and below versions of IE it didn't even hit the service.